# Creating a generic get for foreign keys in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, ef-core-6.0

I have this function

```
public static async Task<Response> GetGeneralizedAsync<T>(int id, string key)
            where T : class
        {
            using var context = new Context();
            var prop = typeof(T).GetProperty(key);

            var list = await context.Set<T>().AsAsyncEnumerable().Where(x => prop.GetValue(x) == (object)id).ToListAsync();
            return new Response(StatusCodes.Status200OK, list);
        }
```

However it only works while using client side evaluation, and I'm worried about performance as this would be a very core function. Is it possible to do the same thing, but have it evaluate on the server, or at least improve the performance?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What are the values for `id` and `key`? Is it an option to use the `DbSet.Find()` method? It is an option to provide a `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` argument instead, which you can use in your `Where()` call?

Comment: Remove `AsAsyncEnumerable` and build the expression tree manually (or use some 3rd party lib like LINQKit). EF query translation works based on `IQueryable` (which `DbSet` implements) otherwise it will need to fetch all data into memory.

Comment: If I do that, I get the error `The LINQ expression... could not be translated`. Fixing that error was the primary reason I had to add `AsAsyncEnumerable`.

Comment: @Progman I am trying to get a list of all entries that have the value `id` for whatever `key`. I'm open to any suggestions as long as I can get that list, but I will not know the value of T, key or id beforehand, and the key will likely not be the primary key.

Comment: @John Where is the value for `key` come from? Is it no option to use a `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` value?

Comment: @Progman it comes from a separate call, such as `var list = GetGeneralizedAsync<People>(38, "Age")`. From what I am gathering from `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`, it seems like it could work, but I would need a more concrete example of that as I'm not familiar with the exact syntax

Comment: [EF.Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.ef.property?view=efcore-6.0) method. `.Where(x => EF.Property<object>(x, key) == (object)id)` ? It might be better to replace `object` with `int`. Reflection is not needed.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov I liked your solution better due to how easy it was to convert to that, however when I extended similar logic to other methods, I ran into strange issues. It did work flawlessly for this exact case, though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Queryable.Where()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.where?view=net-6.0#system-linq-queryable-where-1(system-linq-iqueryable((-0))-system-linq-expressions-expression((system-func((-0-system-boolean)))))) method expects a `Expression<Func<TSource,bool>>` expression, which is used to "evaluate" which entities should be returned when applied on the `Set<T>` instance. You can define your method that such an expression must be provided instead of the `id` and `key` values you have used. The method can look like this:

```
public static async Task<Response> GetGeneralizedAsync<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        where T : class
{
    using var context = new Context();

    var list = await context.Set<T>().Where(predicate)).ToListAsync();
    return new Response(StatusCodes.Status200OK, list);
}
```

Then you use it like this:

```
GetGeneralizedAsync<People>(p => p.Age == 38);
```